# XSLT indentation lost when removing a node

Tags: xslt, indentation

I have the following xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<start>
    <param_1>          
        <short_name>parameter_a</short_name>
    </param_1>
    <param_2>          
        <short_name_2>parameter_b</short_name_2>
    </param_2>
</start>
```

and I have the following XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>        
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />       
    <xsl:template match="/" >  
        <gml:description>
                    <xsl:value-of select="document('/path/to/mydoc.xml')/start/param_1/short_name"/>
    </gml:description>
    <gml:description>
            <xsl:for-each select="document('/path/to/mydoc.xml')/start/param_2">
                <xsl:variable name="my_xlink" select="short_name_2"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$my_offering1_observed_property_xlink"/>    
                <om:observedProperty xlink:href="{$my_offering1_observed_property_xlink}"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
    </gml:description>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this is the output I get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<gml:description>parameter_a</gml:description>
<gml:description>parameter_b<om:observedProperty xlink:href="parameter_b"/></gml:description>
```

the problem is that what I would like to have is this result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <gml:description>parameter_a</gml:description>
    <om:observedProperty xlink:href="parameter_b"/>
```

but if I remove the `<gml:description>` from my XSLT file node the final xml lost its indentation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <gml:description>parameter_a</gml:description><om:observedProperty xlink:href="parameter_b"/>
```

could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: Please post your full XSLT, including the namespace declarations and the xsl:output settings. -- Note that the expected output is not a well-formed XML document (lacks a single root element). Depending on your processor, that might be the reason for lack of indentation.

Comment: Hi michael,
I have just added the declaration of the namespace.
I do not know if it is a problem of declaration or processor because, if I leave the <gml:description> it works. 
but I am probably  misunderstanding something

Comment: Your XSLT is erroneous. For example, it contains two matches for `<xsl:template match="/" >` and misses several closing tags. There is some distance between this code and a [mcve].

Comment: You are perfectly right! there was a problem in copying and pasting!!
I hope now it is correct. thanks!

Comment: So which XSLT processor are we talking about?

Comment: PROCESSOR: libxslt
VERSION: 1.0

Comment: Your XSLT stylesheet is still incomplete.

Comment: As Michael says below, libxslt is probably within its rights to format XML fragments in this way. Is there any reason why you cannot output a well-formed XML document (that has a single outermost element)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a quirk of the `libxslt` processor. I have successfully reproduced the problem using this minimal stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <description/>
    <observedProperty/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<description/><observedProperty/>
```

I don't know if there is a workaround*, since I am unable to reproduce your original result. Since the  result in both cases is an XML fragment, with no root element, I am not sure you have a legitimate reason to complain.

---

(*) except, of course, the obvious:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <description/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <observedProperty/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Actually, looking at my problem, it could be faced from another point of view because, in the end, what would like to achieve is the possibility to change the text "xlink" in the <om:observedProperty xlink:href="xlink"> with the variable "parameter_b" that I'm able to extract using the "for-each" cycle.
Any ideas?

Comment: @sylar_80 I don't see what this has to do with your question, which was about indentation. If you have a problem with the *content* of the output (as opposed to the *form*), post it in a new question.